# Django: Passing extra variables to LoginView using GET?

Tags: django

I need to pass 2 variables to my LoginView, I'm using **Django 3.0**.

I've a template with 2 buttons, 1 for clients and 1 for sellers. Based on which one is clicked I need to send the `typeofuser` in the `GET` call.

This is the template that sends the variables in the GET:

```
{% block content %}
  <h2>Ingresar con tu cuenta</h2>
  <p class="lead">Selecciona qué tipo de usuario eres</p>
  <a href="{% url 'core:login' %}?typeofuser=cliente" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Soy un cliente</a>
  <a href="{% url 'core:login' %}?typeofuser=vendedor" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" role="button">Soy un vendedor</a>
{% endblock %}
```

> I'm showing the same Login page to both `typeofuser`, the difference
>   is only in the title, in the template. That is what I need to send
>   this variable.

My Custom LoginView:

```
class LoginView(SuccessURLAllowedHostsMixin, FormView):
    """
    Display the login form and handle the login action.
    """
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        #context = super(LoginView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        msg = {'cliente': 'Ingresar como cliente', 'vendedor': 'Ingresar como vendedor'}
        context['msg'] = msg.get(self.request.GET.get('typeofuser'), '')
        return context
```

I've also tried this line to get the context:

```
context = super(LoginView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

But I'm getting:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Using this to get the context:

```
context = super(LoginView).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Returns

```
'super' object has no attribute 'get_context_data'
```

**UPDATE 1:**

```
[08/Feb/2020 11:02:29] "GET /ingresar-cliente-vendedor/ HTTP/1.1" 200 20812
Internal Server Error: /ingresar/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\virtual_envs\scolarte\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\virtual_envs\scolarte\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "D:\virtual_envs\scolarte\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\virtual_envs\scolarte\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\virtual_envs\scolarte\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\virtual_envs\scolarte\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 133, in get
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
  File "D:\web_proyects\scolarte\core\views.py", line 31, in get_context_data
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
  File "D:\virtual_envs\scolarte\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 66, in get_context_data
    kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()
  File "D:\virtual_envs\scolarte\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 33, in get_form
    return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
[08/Feb/2020 11:02:31] "GET /ingresar/?typeofuser=cliente HTTP/1.1" 500 93091
```

Comment: The error `'super' object has no attribute 'get_context_data'` rased because of you were calling the `super()` method in the wrong way.  But the error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable ` is strange, Can you add the error traceback?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu please, see uupdate 1.

Comment: I have added an answer, have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not provided any **`form_class`** attribute in the view class hence the error,

```
class LoginView(SuccessURLAllowedHostsMixin, FormView):
    form_class = MyLoginForm
    # other code snippets
```